Pattern matching for Go AST
I try to extract some information from a Go AST. Even very simple tasks do get quite verbose:
//
// Search for top level decleration "var passwd = []*PwEntry{...}".
//
func (this *Source) FindPasswdDecl() *ast.CompositeLit {
    for _, node := range this.AstFile.Decls {
        switch decl := node.(type) {
        case *ast.GenDecl:
            if decl.Tok == token.VAR {
                // fmt.Println("found: var")
                for _, spec := range decl.Specs {
                    switch vspec := spec.(type) {
                    case *ast.ValueSpec:
                        if len(vspec.Names) == 1 && vspec.Names[0].Name == "passwd" {
                            // fmt.Println("found: passwd")
                            if len(vspec.Values) == 1 {
                                switch cl := vspec.Values[0].(type) {
                                case *ast.CompositeLit:
                                    switch clt := cl.Type.(type) {
                                    case *ast.ArrayType:
                                        // fmt.Println("found: []")
                                        switch se := clt.Elt.(type) {
                                        case *ast.StarExpr:
                                            // fmt.Println("found: *")
                                            switch sx := se.X.(type) {
                                            case *ast.Ident:
                                                if sx.Name == "PwEntry" {
                                                    // fmt.Println("found: PwEntry")
                                                    return cl
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}

Does anybody know a pattern matcher for the Go AST?
